# How to derive the integral of a first kind zero-order modified Bessel function multiplied by a Rayleigh distribution?

Tags: evaluation

I input the result into Mathematica and get the following result

In: $\int_{0}^{\infty} \operatorname{BesselI}[0, \epsilon] * \frac{\epsilon}{\rho^{2}} * e^{\left(\frac{-\epsilon^{2}}{2 * \rho^{2}}\right)} d \epsilon$

out:$e^{\frac{\rho^{2}}{2}}$ if $\operatorname{Re}\left[\rho^{2}\right]>0$

I need to use this conclusion in my paper, how do I derive the result step by step? Assuming that it cannot be derived, can I say in the paper that it is based on the results of Mathematica?

Comment: `Expectation[BesselI[0, \[Epsilon]],  Distributed[\[Epsilon], RayleighDistribution[\[Rho]]]]`?

Comment: ... or `Mean@TransformedDistribution[BesselI[0, \[Epsilon]],  Distributed[\[Epsilon], RayleighDistribution[\[Rho]]]]`?

Comment: thx for your comments, but how to calculate the mean of BesselI[0, \[Epsilon]?

Comment: If you want to derive it, expand BesselI[0, \[Epsilon]] into its power series, then interchange the order of integration and summation.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon  Thanks a million！ A brilliant answer.